# Dynamics 365 Plugin Library Failed to get credentials from Windows Vault Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.CrmConnectControl error

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I'm unable to open my Dynamics 365 Plugin Library Solution in Visual Studio 2015

**My Error**

```
Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.CrmConnectControl error @ ReadCredentials
```

[image: Error image]

**My Environment**

Visual Studio running as an Administrator

```
Visual Studio Enterprise 2015
Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3
```

Dynamics Development tools information

```
Microsoft Dynamics CRM SDK Templates
Version: 1.2.100.8427
```

[image: Microsoft Dynamics CRM SDK Templates]

```
Microsoft Dynamics CRM Developer Toolkit
Version: 1.3.2000.9032
```

[image: Microsoft Dynamics CRM Developer Toolkit]

Comment: Have you tried running Visual Studio as Administrator?

Comment: yes same behavior